# Centos python shebang doesn't work for 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot get Centos to use python3. Installed python3 via yum, it has created v3.6. With this test program it works only if I specify the v2 version.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "test"
```

#!/usr/bin/python3 - internal server error 500

#!/usr/bin/python3.6 - internal server error 500

#!/usr/bin/env python3 - internal server error 500

#!/usr/bin/python2.7 - runs

#!/usr/bin/python - runs

#!/usr/bin/env python - runs

If I type python3 at a prompt then it opens the python system, so the links are clearly working.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 16 2020, 16:55:22)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

The links all appear to be correct

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ls -al pyt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Oct 15 23:27 python -> /usr/bin/python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    18 Oct 15 23:27 python2 -> /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7144 Nov 16  2020 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1835 Nov 16  2020 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Oct 15 22:31 python2-config -> pythonl2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Oct 15 23:48 python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 11328 Nov 16  2020 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    14 Oct 15 22:31 python-config -> python2-config
```

There is only one installation of python 3 (and another of python2.7)
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/manningk/.local/bin:/home/manningk/bin

File created from scratch in VI to avoid problems with line endings. Have uninstalled/reinstalled python3 via yum.

File is executable
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache    32 Oct 16 20:39 test2.py

Honestly, I'm stuck. Is it a simple typo I can't see or what? Thanks

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3, not a macro like in Python 2. You need to call `print()`, i.e. with parentheses.

Comment: @MichaelRuth - thank you. It you make that an answer I'll accept it. Spent hours looking for that

Comment: @Wyeknott The question has already been asked, so there's no point writing a new answer. Your solution is on the existing answers.